# How to use `protoreflect.Message.Has`?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-go

Given the following proto spec:

```
message A {
  B b = 1;
}

message B {
  string s = 1;
}
```

and an object `a` of type `A`, how do I check to see if `a.b.s` is set? More specifically, how do I create the `FieldDescriptor` to be passed into `Message.Has()`?

Answer (score 1):

Given some proto object `bv := wrapperspb.BoolValue{}`, one can get the field descriptor for the `value` field with `fd := (&bv).ProtoReflect().Descriptor().Fields().ByName("value")` and check if that field is set with `bv.ProtoReflect().Has(fd)`.